# How to retrieve his own LinkedIN profile data by an API

Tags: api, authentication, linkedin-api, access-token, profile

I would like to test out simple LinkedIN api functionality, e.g to get my personal profile data from linkedIn or any of my posts...
However, I have the problem that is seems that you have to create something like an "app" first, and refer to your company profile, however, I don't have a specific company profile at the moment, and I also cannot grant access for myself to that company. 
Is there any other way or do you have to have a company before trying out the API?

I don't see how there is another way to get your profile id, or something like an access Token / api token from linkedIn otherwise... any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience with Linkedin API I think you will have to create an app before you can do that.

Linkedin uses [OAuth2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2) framework and it is either 3-legged or 2-legged but the 2-legged one which wouldnt be member associated has a lot of restrictions and they dont allow any app to access it, regardless you would need the app.

3-legged is the 3 party one, so Linkedin, an App(Company) and the user(linkedin user).

To create one is quite easy but a company is unfortunely required for it, you can do it [here](http://developers.linkedin.com/)

I struggled a lot with LinkedIn API already and my suggestion would be to try to create a company profile and than an App.

**Edit1: The best workflow to follow is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/context)**

Comment: ok I managed to create an  App with an existing company profile and its verified and I was added as team member, I also got the client_id and client_secret... but now I tried to connect to their API v2 with https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=XXXXXX&client_secret=XXXXX    but got response back : `Error "access_denied" error_description "This application is not allowed to create application tokens"`  What am I missing? I read somewhere I need to contact linkedIn and require special access but how should I contact linkedIN? with what subject?

Comment: @user2774480 before making a request to accessToken you need to make a request  to https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization

Check the edit I did in the answer and follow the workflow in the link

Answer (score 0):

As you said you want any other way to get the **linkedin API**
auth or **access token**, so there no any other way to get the **API**

but you can fetch or retrieve the user's own data without using any **API**  you can customize the LinkedIn's Profile Badge Using JavaScript

Here's an Example using javascript,

In this code-block we are using [Linkedin's Profile Badge](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-create-linkedin-badge-your-website-brynne-tillman/) for retriving user's data then with the help of javascript I'm manipulating the DOM

[Reference Link](https://github.com/codersalman/linkedin-Profile-Data-Fetch-Without-API-) 
[Live Demo Example](https://linkedin-profile.codersalman.workers.dev/)

```js
let lkList = ["devsalmanshaikh"];// replace with user's id that you want to retrive  
let linkedinid = "";
let idx = 0;
let badgeElm = document.getElementById("hideBadgeElm");
let waitObserver;

getData();

function getData() {
  linkedinid = lkList[idx];
  badgeElm.innerHTML = `<div class="badge-base LI-profile-badge" data-locale="en_US" data-size="medium" data-theme="light" data-type="VERTICAL" data-vanity="${linkedinid}" data-version="v1"><a class="badge-base__link LI-simple-link" href="https://in.linkedin.com/in/${linkedinid}?trk=profile-badge">.</a></div>`;
  loadProfileJs();
}

function loadProfileJs() {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.onload = function() {
    waitObserver = setInterval(domObserve, 1000);
  };
  script.src = "https://platform.linkedin.com/badges/js/profile.js";
  document.head.appendChild(script);
}

function domObserve() {
  let state = badgeElm.querySelector(".LI-profile-badge .profile-badge__header");
  if (state) {
    clearInterval(waitObserver);
    console.log(state);
    let json = {
      id: linkedinid,
      img: "#",
      name: "Not available",
      title: "Not available",
      info: "Not available",
    };

    if (badgeElm.querySelector("img.profile-badge__content-profile-image")) {
      json.img = badgeElm.querySelector("img.profile-badge__content-profile-image").src;
    }

    if (badgeElm.querySelector(".profile-badge__content-profile-name")) {
      json.name = badgeElm.querySelector(".profile-badge__content-profile-name").innerText;
    }

    if (badgeElm.querySelector(".profile-badge__content-profile-headline")) {
      json.title = badgeElm.querySelector(".profile-badge__content-profile-headline").innerText;
    }

    if (badgeElm.querySelector(".profile-badge__content-profile-company-school-info")) {
      json.info = badgeElm.querySelector(".profile-badge__content-profile-company-school-info").innerText;
    }

   
    showData(json);
  }
}

function showData(json) {
  let tbl = "<table border=1><tbody>";
  for (i in json) tbl += `<tr><td class='col0'>${i}</td><td class='col1'>${json[i]}</td></tr>`;
  output.innerHTML += tbl + "</tbody></table>";
  idx++;
  if (idx < lkList.length) getData();
}
```

```html
<h4>Example of Profile Data Fetch without API using javascript </h4>

<div id="output" style="padding: 12px;"></div>

<div id="hideBadgeElm" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.